# getting input type values with same name on next page without using URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

Used the following code to add textbox dynamically using JQUERY in jsp page(one.jsp):
[How To Add Textbox Dynamically With JQuery](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-add-remove-textbox-dynamically-with-jquery/)

Say, a user adds 3 textboxes by clicking on "ADD TEXTBOX" and after entering these values user clicks on submit.
After submission I want to access these 3 values under multiple input type textboxes name myarray[] on next page(nextpage.jsp).
Actually I want to access these values on next page(jsp page).

Tried using request.getparameter, but it resulted in retrieving the first value i.e 1st index:
Taken name as "myarray[]" and accessed it using
         `<%= request.getParameter("myarray[]")%> : my array values` on 
next page`

What should I do now, is there an alternative to do so or some changes to be done here:
This is the form in page one.jsp:

```
<form action="nextpage.jsp" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<b>Add value in separate textboxes:</b>
     <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
        <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
         <label>newvalue #1 : </label><input type='textbox' id='textbox1' name="myarray[]">
        </div>
     </div>
     <input type='button' value='Add textbox' id='addButton'><br />

   <input type="submit" value="Click to get result on next page"/><br /><br />
```

Below is the code snippet:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

 div{
        padding:8px;
    }



 </style>

 </head>
<body>

    <h2>Code for adding multiple textboxes dynamically... <br /></h2> 


     <br />

<script type="text/javascript">
                   $(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 2;

    $("#addButton").click(function () {

    if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
    }   

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>newvalue #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
          '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
          '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


    counter++;
     });
        });          
  </script>
```

Note: ignore the counter value as it is just taken here for checking purpose, the code is running correctly but it is retrieving only the 1st index value using request.getparameter.
Please suggest me something, newbie to JQUERY and Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the same name in your input's name attribute, to do that you have to edit your line

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>newvalue #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
      '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');
```

To this :

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>newvalue #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" name="myarray[]" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');
```

In yout jsp page you do : <%= request.getParameterValues("myarray[]")%>

keep in mind : you don't have to put "[]" in jsp or any other language excepte for php

Comment: I have corrected that mistake, thanks...now how to get this value on next page, <%= request.getParameter("myarray[]")%> as shown above is retrieving single value as index 1st value..means textbox 1 value only on next page...how to retrieve all values(3 here) on next page

Comment: You have just to remove "[]" frome your input and in your jsp page so you can do : 
request.getParameterValues("myarray")
and <input type="text" name="myarray" ...

Comment: <%= request.getParameterValues("myarray")%> is retrieving null on next page

Comment: Lamarai Alla, you were right....Just noticed something you mentioned above..you were correct to remove +counter+ here name="textbox' + counter + and write only name="myarray[]" here :) thanks..selecting this as answer

Comment: happy to help, but you have to keep in mind that you don't have to put "[]" in jsp or any other language excepte for php

Comment: thanks, this was even more confusing...will remember that now..doubt cleared

Answer (score 1):

> the code is running correctly but it is retrieving only the 1st index value using request.getparameter.

Use [getParameterValues](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29) method

```
String[] valueArray = request.getParameterValues("myarray[]");
```

**Returns an array of String objects** containing all of the values the given request parameter `myarray[]` has, or `null` if the parameter does not exist.

Comment: Now this is returning [Ljava.lang.String;@5cab4d : after submission on next page....Now after what you have written I printed it like this: for(int i=0;i<valueArray.length;i++)
       {
           out.println("<li>"+valueArray[i]+"</li>");
       }  // Now this only printing the first textbox value of myarray

Comment: Thanks Aniket, your comments helped me too...I noticed the answer given by Lamari again and found the solution :)